# Как правильно работать с конкретным элементом класса в Jquery, если контент динамический?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть динамически создаваемые элементы "товары". У каждого элемента есть форма добавления в корзину. Через атрибут data я передаю id товара для отправки на бекэнд. Проблема в том, что когда я вызываю id уже в js коде, мне дают id не того элемента, который пытались добавить в корзину, а первого, который подходит под селектор. Я понимаю, что по логике это верно. Собственно вопрос как сделать так, чтобы id передавался именно того, элемента на котором была нажата кнопка добавить в корзину?

```js
$(".cart-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var btn = $(".cart-btn");
        var product_id = btn.data("product_id");

    })
```

```html
{% for new_product in new_products %}
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <a class="product-link" href="{{ new_product.get_absolute_url }}">
      <div class="card product-cell">
        <img class="card-img" src="{{ new_product.image.url }}" alt="">
        <div class="card-caption products-card-caption">
             <span class="product-name">{{ new_product.title }}</span><br>
             <span class="price">{{ new_product.price }} руб.</span><br>
             <form action="#" class="form-inline cart-form">
             {% csrf_token %}
             <input type="number" class="number-input" value="1">
             <button type="submit" class="cart-btn" data-product_id="{{ new_product.id }}">
                  <img src="{% static 'png/shopping-cart.png' %}" alt="В корзину">
             </button>

         </form>
       </div>

     </div>
   </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно искать `.cart-btn` не по всему документу, а внутри кликнутой формы:

```
var btn = $(this).find(".cart-btn");
```

Comment: Благодарю. Именно то, что нужно.